# Postgressql Xmltable as string for input to procedure problem

Tags: postgresql, insert, plpgsql, xmltable

Hello iam trying to use xmltable in function, to update some data in other table, as for input i got string

This is a test program the final result will be that the insert should be created from any xml doing some data adjustment

the xml look like this

```
<header>
    <data>
        <line>
            <field1>some data in f1</field1>
            <field2>other data f2</field2>
            <field3>this data contains numers 012323</field3>
            <field4>and the last data</field4>
       <line>               
    </data>             
</header>
```

Iam taking the next steps

create table with casted string to xml input values

```
create table if not exists test_xml_table as select input_string::xml as string_xml;
```

will do some data adjustments

final step is insert

```
insert into test_tab( field1, field2, field3, field4 ) 
    select xt.field1, xt.field2, xt.field3, field4 from test_xml_table 
    cross join xmltable( '/data/line' passing string_xml
        columns field1 text path 'field1', field2 text path 'field2', 
        field3 text path 'field3', field4 text path 'field4' ) as xt;
```

The problem is that if the table **test_xml_table** doesnt exists, the program dont create it ( still didnt see it after create table command. I tried to do workaround, create the table first and fill it with XML data but now i dont know what to put after PASSING phrase. There is no error just no data is inserted. Will be grateful for help

the whole code is below

```
create or replace function test_function(

input_string character varying )
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql

as $BODY$

begin 
create table test_xml_table as select input_string::xml as string_xml;
    
insert into test_tab( field1, field2, field3, field4 ) 
    select xt.field1, xt.field2, xt.field3, field4 from test_xml_table 
    cross join xmltable( '/data/line' passing string_xml
        columns field1 text path 'field1', field2 text path 'field2', 
        field3 text path 'field3', field4 text path 'field4' ) as xt;
                                        
end;

$BODY$;
```

call ->

```
select test_function( '<header>
    <data>
      <line>
         <field1>some data in f1</field1>
         <field2>other data f2</field2>
         <field3>this data contains numers 012323</field3>
         <field4>and the last data</field4>
       </line>              
     </data>                
</header>'   )
```

Tried to use postgres xmltable function to insert data into table. Iam expecting that the data from function input that is type *character varying* will insert data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cross join` is not needed.

The xml `namespace_uri` should be `/header/data/line` not just `/data/line`

```
    create or replace function test_function( input_string character varying )
      RETURNS void
      LANGUAGE plpgsql
      as $BODY$
      begin 
      create table test_xml_table as select input_string::xml as string_xml;
      insert into test_tab( field1, field2, field3, field4 ) 
        select xt.field1, xt.field2, xt.field3, field4 
        from test_xml_table, xmltable( '/header/data/line' passing string_xml
            columns 
               field1 text path 'field1', 
               field2 text path 'field2', 
               field3 text path 'field3', 
               field4 text path 'field4' 
        ) as xt;                                   
    end;
    
    $BODY$;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/J-9YPC2g)